# Crypt giving different length hash since changing server

Tags: php, password-encryption, crypt

I'm going crazy here!

I have moved a database and website to a new server.

The code I am using to generate the passoword on signup is:

```
$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ./';
$numChars = strlen($chars);
$salt = '';

for($i = 0; $i < 22; ++$i) {
    $salt .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $numChars - 1)];
}

$p_hash = crypt($p, '$2a$12$' . $salt);
```

This code has not changed since the site went up. Neither has the login script:

```
$pCheck = crypt($p,$dbPass);
```

However, since changing servers, the passwords no longer match.

I have used var_dump to check the salt, password and hashed password and the problem seems to be the length of the string `crypt()` is creating.

The password stored in the database and created using the script above is 60 chars long, whereas running the same script on the new server returns a 13 char long string.

I have been up and down the internet and can find nothing relating to my problem. I read that `crypt()` does trim the string but couldn't find any more info on it.

Is there a reason that the same script would work differently on 2 different servers?

Comment: its mentioned on doc 'crypt() will return a hashed string using the standard Unix DES-based algorithm or alternative algorithms that `may be available on the system.`'

Comment: I read that and didn't fully understand it. Does this mean I am going to have to change the passwords for all the users?

Comment: According to manual, you may check whether CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 to know whether it can be used or not.

Comment: check the php version A bug was fixed in PHP 5.3.2: Fixed Blowfish behaviour on invalid rounds to return "failure" string ("*0" or "*1"), instead of falling back to DES. `Try to match the PHP version` to avoid password reset

Comment: @matt1985 - To write it explicitely, it seems that your new server runs an old PHP version and doesn't support BCrypt, the BCrypt algorithm `'2a'` is supported since 5.3.0., `'2y'` since 5.3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP was version 5.2 on the new server. Upgrade PHP to 5.3.28 and all good now :)

Thanks for the suggestions guys!